# Diagrammatic Ward Identity for the QED vertex

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, ward-identity

The QED Ward identity for the vertex reads
\begin{equation}
q^\mu\Gamma^\mu(p,p')=\Sigma(p)-\Sigma(p')
\end{equation}
with $q=p-p'$. In the limit $q\rightarrow 0$,
\begin{equation}
\Gamma^\mu(p,p)=\frac{\partial}{\partial p_\mu}\Sigma(p).
\end{equation}
These identities can also be proven diagrammatically, and relate subsets of diagrams contributing to the vertex correction to subsets of diagrams contributing to the electron's self-energy. The second one was used, for example, in the computation of the anomalous magnetic moment of the electron (by Aoyama, Kinoshita, Nio).

As an example of the diagrammatic application of this identity, consider the following equality

[image]

where the dashed line is the photon. The proof of the Ward identity, at a diagrammatic level, proceeds by adding all possible photon insertions to the fermionic lines. Insertions that attach to closed fermion loops are argued to be vanishing. Photonic insertions should then only be added to the open fermion lines, hence the diagrammatic identity I have above.

My question is the following: which group of diagrams belong to the right hand-side of the following equation?

[image]

If we think of the Ward identity as performing all attachments to all fermion lines, then the diagram on the left is obtained by attaching a photon to a closed fermion loop, which would give zero contribution. This can also be seen as a consequence of Furry's theorem: the diagram in which the external photon is deleted has a blob with three photons attaching, which is zero. I cannot wrap my head around how this works in this case.

Comment: Hi Tanatofobico. Is this from a reference/link? Which page?

Comment: Hi! No, it's a project I'm working on. I have to study QED corrections to g-2. I was looking at the Light-By-Light contribution to g-2, which is defined in terms these diagrams with four photons attached to the blob. I thought of using the Ward identity to simplify the study and noticed these Light-By-Light contributions should be zero because of the Ward identity.

Comment: For confirmation I looked at previous computations of g-2, and indeed they also use the Ward identity and do not seem to include diagrams of the blob-form I included in the last equation (look at https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.06060, https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.3496, https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9602417 etc.). So I was looking at confirmation that my use of the Ward identity to exclude the computation of the LBL diagrams is correct.